# RxAndroidBle2 working differently in scanning and connecting across Android phone models

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, interop, rxandroidble

First of all, thanks to Polidea for the excellent ReactiveX based library for Android BLE (RxAndroidBle2)!

As I came across the library, I have replaced my BLE usage in my Android app completely with RxAndroidBle, and this took away a lot of problems I had with BLE and Java native BT API. My app is intended to connect to and to steer a BLE peripheral. Below I copy-pasted my usage of RxAndroidBle as an example from my Android Java code.

Yet I do not completely understand why is RxAndroidBle working seamlessly and good with newer Android models, whereas it has problems with older Android models.

The problem is that some older phones can indeed scan and find the device, but then can’t connect to the BT peripheral after finding the right device. Devices that have problems connecting are for example Huawei P8 Lite (Android 6.0) and Asus Zenfone Go ZB500KL (Android 6.0). The same code works wonderfully in new devices.

So my questions:

1. How do I know, in which phone models or Android versions the RxAndroidBle2 library 1.5.0 should work the same way as it works in >6.0 Android versions.
2. Why is scanning working always in all Android devices >5.0, but connecting not in all Android devices <= 6.0.

Thanking in advance for any answers!

Examples from my code:

Scanning----

```
scanDisposable = rxBleClient.scanBleDevices(
      new ScanSettings.Builder()
            .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
            .setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES)
            .build(),
      new ScanFilter.Builder()
            .setServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(Globals.uuid_my_service))
            .build()
)
      .compose(bindUntilEvent(FragmentEvent.PAUSE))
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      .take(scanTimeMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
      .doFinally(this::dispose)
      .subscribe(this::addScanResult, this::onScanFailure);
```

Connecting----

```
connectionDisposable = bleDevice.establishConnection(false)
      .compose(bindUntilEvent(PAUSE))
      .flatMapSingle(connection ->
            connection.discoverServices()
                  .flatMap(services -> services.getService(Globals.uuid_my_service))
                  .map(service -> service.getCharacteristic(Globals.uuid_program_characteristic))
                  .flatMap(characteristic -> connection
                        .writeCharacteristic(characteristic, programData))
      )
      .doFinally(this::dispose)
      .subscribe(
            characteristic -> {
               Log.i(tag, characteristic.toString());
               bluetoothResponses.msgToUserOnSuccess("\n" + "Success...");
               atomicSuccess.set(true);
            },
            throwable -> {
               bluetoothResponses.onConnectionFailure(throwable);
            });
```

Comment: And what is the actual problem? Could you add logs with `RxBleLog.setLogLevel(RxBleLog.VERBOSE)`?

Comment: I already have logging enabled, and will post here after I get logs from live devices. This takes a few days though, devices are out there... Anyway, there is a lot of different behaviour depending on phone model in question.

Comment: Another question: do you always stop the scan before starting a connection?

Comment: That's a great hint. I was not calling scanDisposable.dispose(), only setting scanDisposable = null. Let's see if this will affect the devices with older Android versions!

Comment: Adding call to dispose() after scanning and connecting makes it to work in many phone models, so this was a great hint. I would like to check how this is explained in RxAndroidBle API documentation. Maybe it's good to mention there, that in some models scanning and connecting works even without calling dispose(), but to cover widest number of devices, dispose() should be always called. Yet there are phone models where it doesn't work overall. I'm trying to get more information about the cause in them.

Comment: Hello, any news yet?

Comment: From the phone models that have problems, I have some test results now. It is showing that in some Huawei P8 Lite devices this works with no problems, while in other Huawei P8 Lite devices it does not work. Quality deviations in Huawei phones? I am continuing to investigate. Settings and app versions are the same. This has become quite interesting now.

Comment: I have seen P8 Lite's BLE stack going nuts. The device would continuously scan even when the application did finish the scan. Then every attempt to start a BLE connection would be rejected with status `Command Disallowed (0x0c)` immediately but the system would call error with `status=133` after 30 seconds. The only thing that fixes it (afaik) is a factory reset.

Comment: Very interesting. We'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently it is not the stack on Huawei's and potentially other devices that is broken but rather [a crappy BT chip and overzealous system apps](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/29128/long-connection-delay-with-android-ios-superfast/115710#115710)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I know, in which phone models or Android versions the RxAndroidBle2 library 1.5.0 should work the same way as it works in >6.0 Android versions.

You don't — the BLE implementation is very different from vendor to vendor, device, chip etc. There are too many combinations and there are too many device specific bugs.

> Why is scanning working always in all Android devices >5.0, but connecting not in all Android devices <= 6.0.

Some implementations of BLE stack are buggy. Sometimes they just fail randomly but when retrying right away everything starts to work. Sometimes an additional time (~500 ms) between the scan and connecting does the trick.

Huawei P8 Lite (6.0) has a crappy BLE chip which does not handle scanning and connecting at the same time. Apparently sometimes [the NearbyMessageService from Google Play Services scans continuously in the background](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/29128/long-connection-delay-with-android-ios-superfast/115710#115710) and prevents a successful connection. This situation may display on other vendor/devices as well. As a developer you can do nothing about it.